# How should I arrange multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a web app and need some advise on how to organize database information. Following is a list of all information the app will have:

**1) There will be users which will be stored in a table like so:**

```
User
 - username (primary key)
 - email
```

**2) Users can create maps(which are represented by a table like so)**

```
Map
 - name
 - data
```

---

Users can create many maps

Using a mySQL database, how should I achieve a storage system like I described above:

- Should I have one table which stores the maps of all users? Then create a new 'username' field in the Map table.
- Should I create a new map table for every new user which only stores that users maps.
- Should I create a new 'maps' field in user and then link that to a Map table?

In the end I want each user to have access and view only there own collection of maps. 
I am new to mySQL and database design so would appreciate any advise on this.

Comment: and this maps can be used by many users or not?

Comment: Users create their own maps which only they will have access to. Some users may not create any maps, but all user have the ability to create maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentions that users can create many maps, I think, you only need two tables for this (*not many maps table for every user*)

**User**

- userID (*Primary Key*)
- userName (*unique*)
- email

**Map**

- ID (*Primary Key*)
- name
- date
- userID (*Foreign Key*)

when tranlated into DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    UserID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserName VARCHAR(15),
    Email VARCHAR(35),
    CONSTRAINT usr_pk PRIMARY KEY(UserID),
    CONSTRAINT usr_uq UNIQUE(UserName)
);

CREATE TABLE Maps
(
    MapID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Date DATETIME,
    UserID INT,
    CONSTRAINT map_pk PRIMARY KEY(MapID),
    CONSTRAINT map_FK FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID)
);
```

when you want to get all maps for all users,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Name
FROM    User a
        INNER JOIN Maps b
            ON a.UserID = b.UserID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @JamieFearon `INNODB`, of course. `MyISAM` doesnt support relationships.

Comment: When I run these two queries in phpmyadmin it successfully creates the tables, but the table are MyISAM. If I manually change them to INNODB in the operations tab, then will all be ok?

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* create a new table for each user for maps.  This would be a nightmare to maintain, and you would lose control over normalization.  Similar comments apply to point #3 (new `maps` column for each user map).

Do your first point: add a username column on *maps*.  Then you can have one table for maps and create as many maps per user as you wish.  I would take it a step further and add an `auto_increment` "user ID" column that links to the maps (usernames may change after all -- and should still be unique).  Map should also have its own `auto_increment` identifier column.  This is called a "surrogate key."

```
SELECT data FROM Map JOIN User USING(userID) WHERE userID = ?
```

Comment: Thank you so will calling SELECT data FROM Map JOIN User USING(userID) WHERE userID = foo only return maps that belong to userID

Comment: Am I right in thinking your solution does not require the need to create Foreign keys like JW's solution does?

Comment: @JamieFearon no, you can still create foreign keys.  There's never a *need* to, it would just prevent orphaned Map records

Comment: Please could you edit your answer to include the SQL query to create these two tables. I would really appreciate it as I'm really new to this and want to learn. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JamieFearon JW has that covered

Answer (score 0):

One of the best db design I ever got was to create a Table for each noun, (and in singular). For instance you are talking about users. That means that you will have the user Table. Then you have a Map Table to list all the maps created.

Then you are talking about the relation between users an map, so you may call that table UserMapRelationship or simply UsersMap

This one will hold the pk for both tables and probably information related for that relationship.

Hope this have helped.

Thanks!

@leo.